# My CSS doesn't work anymore since I'm using angular4

Tags: css, angular

My CSS doesn't work anymore since I'm using angular4.

Currently building the base template of the app, I've somes difficulties with the CSS which is not applying correctly on DIVS because of the generated Component DOM element of Angular.

**This is what I want (1)**

```
 <div class="page-container ">
   <div class="page-content-wrapper">

    <div class="content">
        Content here
    </div>

    <div class="container-fluid container-fixed-lg footer">
        Footer here
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

**This is what I have (2)**

```
 <div class="page-container ">
   <div class="page-content-wrapper">

    <div class="content">
      <router-outlet>
        Content here
      </router-outlet>
    </div>

    <ae-footer-composant>
      <div class="container-fluid container-fixed-lg footer">
        Footer here
      </div>
    </ae-footer-composant>
  </div>
</div>
```

**This is my index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="fr">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Pages - Admin Dashboard UI Kit - Blank Page</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, shrink-to-fit=no" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="pages/ico/60.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="pages/ico/76.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="pages/ico/120.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="pages/ico/152.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta name="apple-touch-fullscreen" content="yes">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="default">
    <meta content="" name="description" />
    <meta content="" name="author" />

    <base href="/">

    <!--[if lte IE 9]>
    <link href="assets/plugins/codrops-dialogFx/dialog.ie.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <![endif]-->

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/plugins/jquery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" ></script>
  </head>
  <body class="fixed-header">

    <app-root></app-root>


    <!-- Styles -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/plugins/pace/pace-theme-flash.css"  />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/plugins/bootstrapv3/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/plugins/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/plugins/jquery-scrollbar/jquery.scrollbar.css" media="screen"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/plugins/select2/css/select2.min.css" media="screen" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/plugins/switchery/css/switchery.min.css" media="screen"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/pages/css/pages-icons.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/pages/css/pages.css" class="main-stylesheet"/>
    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/pages/condensed/css/pages.css" class="main-stylesheet"/>-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/plugins/bootstrap3-wysihtml5/bootstrap3-wysihtml5.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/plugins/bootstrap-tag/bootstrap-tagsinput.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/plugins/dropzone/css/dropzone.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/plugins/bootstrap-datepicker/css/datepicker3.css" media="screen">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/plugins/summernote/css/summernote.css" media="screen">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/plugins/bootstrap-daterangepicker/daterangepicker-bs3.css" media="screen">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/plugins/bootstrap-timepicker/bootstrap-timepicker.min.css" media="screen">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/plugins/jquery-datatable/media/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/plugins/jquery-datatable/extensions/FixedColumns/css/dataTables.fixedColumns.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/plugins/datatables-responsive/css/datatables.responsive.css" media="screen" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/css/style.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/elium-style/css/elium.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/elium-style/css/pages.css"/>

  </body>
</html>
```

**This is my app.component.html**

```
<!-- START PAGE-CONTAINER -->
<div class="page-container ">

  <!-- START HEADER -->
  <ae-header-composant></ae-header-composant>

  <!-- START PAGE CONTENT WRAPPER -->
  <div class="page-content-wrapper">

    <div class="content">
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>

    <ae-footer-composant></ae-footer-composant>
  </div>
  <!-- END PAGE CONTENT WRAPPER -->

</div>
<!-- END PAGE CONTAINER -->

<ae-quickview-composant></ae-quickview-composant>
<ae-overlay-composant></ae-overlay-composant>
<ae-css-composant></ae-css-composant>
```

My CSS works with the (1), but not with the (2) because of the generated DOM of angular...

I already try the following, but still not working ...

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation} from '@angular/core';  

 @Component({
      selector: 'ae-sidebar-composant',
      templateUrl: './sidebar-composant.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./sidebar-composant.component.css'],
      encapsulation: **ViewEncapsulation.None**,
    })
    export class SidebarComposantComponent implements OnInit {

      constructor() { }

      ngOnInit() {
      }
}
```

Does anyone have an idea ? 
Thank's

Comment: Why are you having all the components in the index.html?? Which is your root component that is Bootstrapped when you're module load

Comment: Do they have a parent child relationship ?

Comment: What Angular version did your CSS work with? What does the CSS look like that doesn't work anymore?

Comment: Sorry @Aravind, just did a mistake when I made my post, just edited now.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, I'm using Angular4, my css work without using angular application. But because angular add some "DOM Html component" ie:<ae-footer-component></ae-footer-component> my CSS doesn't...

Comment: Is all of your css not working? or just your custom css? sounds like you might have some parent direct child css definitions that is breaking because angular insert DOM elements

Answer (score 0):

angular uses webpack . You must have a css loader in  your webpack.config.js file .
if right, check if you have a src/style.css file in which you can import other styles.

or you can  add your css in webpack.config.js  as follow :

```
 "styles": [
      "./src/styles.css",
    "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css", // if you have setted up ng-bootstrap ...
    ]
```